# sample of a large json file

Tags: json, r, dplyr

I have a large JSON file (8 GB, 8 million cases) but I only need a small sample of it. Simple `stream_in` doesn`t work because the file is too large.

To solve the problem I tried the following code:

```
books <- list("Books_5.json") 
books <- map(books, ~ stream_in(file(.x)) %>% sample_n(385))
books <- as.data.frame(books)
```

The problem is that after 3 million pages R stops reading in the file because the file is so large. Any Idea how I can get a sample of 385 cases of that file?

Example of a smaller file. The variables are the same.

```
Variables: 9
$ reviewerID     <chr> "AF50PEUSO9MSV", "A1L0TVAJ1TYE06", "A64NRL5OSR3KB", ...
$ asin           <chr> "B0000A1G05", "B009SQQF9C", "B005HRT88G", "B00D5T3QK...
$ reviewerName   <chr> "Matthew J. Hodgkins", "TCG", "Me", "J. Lee", "A. Bu...
$ helpful        <list> [<1, 1>, <0, 1>, <1, 1>, <0, 0>, <0, 0>, <0, 0>, <0...
$ reviewText     <chr> "This is the lens that I always keep on my camera by...
$ overall        <dbl> 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 2, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4...
$ summary        <chr> "Great lens!", "I love them! What else can I say", "...
$ unixReviewTime <int> 1370736000, 1404518400, 1387411200, 1385769600, 1379...
$ reviewTime     <chr> "06 9, 2013", "07 5, 2014", "12 19, 2013", "11 30, 2...
```

Comment: Could you provide some example data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file has one case per line you could use the `LaF` package to do this very efficiently:

```
library(LaF)
random_lines <- sample_lines(filename = "Books_5.json",
    n = 385)
```

You might then have to transform the lines into your required format, but this solution allows to read from huge files without reading everything into memory.

**Edit:**
Transforming the resulting lines into a `data.frame`:

```
do.call("rbind",lapply(random_lines, fromJSON))
```

This should work as long as the fields in the JSON-object only contain single values (i.e. are not nested).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don´t know how to transform the resulting character string back to the original data frame again.

Comment: DIfficult to say without knowing how the resulting character string looks like... have you tried `jsonlite::fromJSON()`?

Comment: The file looks like this: 
 `chr [1:385] "{\"reviewerID\": \"A29BC531E6553J\", \"asin\": \"0812510011\", \"reviewerName\": \"Richard Rivera\", \"helpful\"| __truncated__ ...`

Comment: And what does `jsonlite::fromJSON(random_lines)` or `jsonlite::fromJSON(random_lines[1])` result in?

Comment: `jsonlite::fromJSON(random_lines)` results in: `Error: parse error: trailing garbage
           "reviewTime": "12 7, 2013"} {"reviewerID": "A2RJUDHGHJTQ4X"
                     (right here) ------^` and `fromJSON(random_lines[1])` results in `List of 9`

Comment: What about `do.call("rbind",lapply(random_lines, fromJSON))` ?